# Does mongodb-core supports mongodb commands such as "db.getCollection('abcd.data').count()", if so how to run it?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I can't seem to find relevant documents on its [official documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/core/driver/reference/crud/), and my imagination is I can do this:

```
const mongoServer = require('mongodb-core').Server;
let mongo = new mongoServer({host: 'localhost', port: 27017});
mongo.on('connect', function(mongo) {
  mongo.command('db.getCollection("abcd.data").count()'
    , {ismaster: true}
    , {
      readPreference: new ReadPreference('secondary')
    }, function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log(result);
      }
      server.destroy();
  });
});
mongo.connect();
```

My imagination is wrong apparently...

Answer (score 0):

Mongodb driver provides a method like that. You can use the below code to get the count from a collection:

```
    const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    const assert = require('assert');

    // Connection URL
    const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';

    // Database Name
    const dbName = 'movies';

    // Use connect method to connect to the server
    MongoClient.connect(url, (err, client) => {
      assert.equal(null, err);
      console.log("Connected successfully to server");
      const db = client.db(dbName);
        // Get the documents collection
        const collection = db.collection('movieNames');
        // Find some documents
       collection.find({}).count().then( (count) => {
          console.log(count);
        });
      client.close();
    });
```

Comment: My question is about mongodb-core, a lower level driver of which mongodb relies on.